# How to add JS file to all pages in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, javascript

Let's assume I have a company named `Company` and I'm developing a magento module named `Module`. What I want my module to do is simple: Add a JavaScript file to header tag of **ALL** pages in magento. But for some reason, it doesn't add the script in any pages.

**Note:** Currently I'm testing it for frontend.

**Note 2:**:I'm using XAMPP (php 5.6, mysql 5.6, apache 2) if that's relevant.

Here is my directory tree:

```
Root
├───app
│   ├───code
│   │   └───local
│   │       └───Company
│   │           └───Module
│   │               └───etc
│   │                       config.xml
│   │
│   ├───design
│   │   └───frontend
│   │       └───base
│   │           └───default
│   │               └───layout
│   │                       module.xml
│   │
│   └───etc
│       └───modules
│               Company_Module.xml
│
└───js
    └───company
            module.js
```

Content of `app\etc\modules\Company_Module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Content of `app\code\local\Company\Module\etc\config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>   
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <module>
                    <file>module.xml</file> 
                </module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Content of `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>company/module.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Content of `js\company\module.js` :

```
alert('Yes!');
```

Comment: Cleat all cache in admin end and try again. Also check you module enable or disabled under System -> Configuration -> Advanced under Advanced tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contents of `app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <name>Company </name>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <module>
                    <file>company_module.xml</file>
                </module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
 <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <module>
                    <file>company_module.xml</file>
                </module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

Contents of `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/company_module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action  method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>company/module/javascript.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Path to JS file:  `js/company/module/javascript.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can add your javascript file  by adding a addJs method in page.xml file.

Comment: I can't edit that file. I need a way to add javascript without editing core files. I have to give this module to my customers, so adding or editing core files is **NOT** an option. I'll look  for a way to override or extend that file. Thanks.

Comment: I thought to copy page.xml to your theme. You can add javascript to your layout file of your module. Reference to your root xml block then add js

Comment: Add the JS file somewhere into js folder and paste  the following code to your XML layout file on your module

`<default>
<reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>folder/file.js</script></action>
  </reference>
</default>`

Comment: OK I'll try that and will let you know what happens.